# Meteor Project not supported

Tags: meteor

I am trying to run a project on meteor but getting this error in the command line-

> this project uses Meteor1.0.2.1, which isn't available on Windows. To
>   work with is app on all supported platforms, use ,meteor update
>   --release METEOR@1.1.0.2 to pin this app to the  newest Windows-compatible release.

I have tried updating to which I am getting the error message

> while checking for meteorhacks:kadira-binary-deps@1.2.1:error: No
>   compatible binary build found for this package. Contact the package
>   author and ask them to publish it for your platform.

I tried updating this to which i was brought back to the first error message.

Does anyone know how I can run this meteor package? It is sparrow-finance to be specific.

Regards 
Chris

Comment: I think the second error is pretty clear: the package you are trying to use simply doesn't exist for windows. Can you live without kadira?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply remove the kadira package which you can do by editing the packages file in .meteor.

But, kadira is really useful. So what I'd suggest is to set up meteor environments. Meteor cookbook has a good example of this - https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/environment-detection.md .

If your environment is anything other than local, use kadira, else don't use it.